# Embed and change data inside an executable

Tags: c#, file, executable

Is it possible to put a text file into an executable and then make changes to the file while the program is running? I need to do this because im making a portable program that needs a password to open, and the user needs to be able to change the password.

Comment: I don't know about changing the executable itself.  Perhaps instead you can read/write to an external encrypted file that uses the password as part/all of the encryption key?

Comment: i dont want the user to accidently delete it, or something else to delete it on purpose

Comment: Perhaps you could use an encrypted registry entry?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There would be so called "Alternate Data Streams" ideal for such task. The executable of your portable program would be inaccessible by normal way for appending data like a text file to it, if the application currently runs, but it's still accessible for adding "Alternate Data Streams".
An example / article on how to add "Alternate Data Streams" to a file exists here: [Manipulate-Alternate-Data-Streams](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9387/Manipulate-Alternate-Data-Streams). Just re-write the example to add the stream to your own executable. It works like a hidden file property, which stays unknown to the user as long the "property name" isn't known. Even in this case the user needs a tool to make the property / datastream visible.

Comment: this is just what i was looking for thanks, +1 for the article